# How to write an action listener for multiple Jbuttons

Tags: java, awt, swt

```
    //Created a composite with label and text field
    Label label = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
    label.setText("Test:");        
    labelTxt = new Text(composite, SWT.BORDER);
    labelTxt.setText("56");         //value here might be empty or might be already set with 
                                  // any value from demo image
    
    labelTxt.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseUp(MouseEvent arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDown(MouseEvent arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println(" mouse double clicked");
            // I created a pop up on double click with buttons here. 
            ///The pop up image is attached for reference
        }
    });
```

Demo image:
[image: demo image]

Now what I need is if I click any button from pop up the button value should be saved to "labelTxt ".
i.e. if I click button R6 then R6 should be saved in labelTxt.

Comment: This looks like SWT code - which doesn't use things like `JButton` - don't try and mix SWT and AWT/Swing, it doesn't work.

Comment: I am not trying to mix the code actually up to pop up it is fine. I am not able to set text to required field as the buttons and text field both are on different shells.

Comment: It makes no difference that they are in different shells, SWT and AWT/Swing have different event loops making it hard to get code using both of them to work properly. To make it work at all you need to use `SWT_AWT.new_Frame` - are you doing that?

Comment: Yes I have used like  "java.awt.Frame fileFrame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(treeComp);"

Comment: But why are you using AWT/Swing for this? It doesn't seem like anything that can't be done easily in SWT. Trying to set the value of SWT Labels from AWT callbacks seems likely to be problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code implements to pop-up you show in SWT and sets the `labelTxt` field. Since it is all SWT there are no issues with AWT/SWT interaction. It assumes that `labelTxt` is a field in the containing class.

The code uses the JFace `GridDataFactory` and `GridLayoutFactory` but can be converted to just SWT if required. It also uses `var` so Java 10 or later is needed (again could be changed to Java 8).

```java
private void openPopup(final Shell parentShell)
{
  final var shell = new Shell(parentShell, SWT.ON_TOP | SWT.TOOL);

  shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

  // Composite for the main set of buttons

  final var body = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);

  GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().align(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER).grab(true, false).applyTo(body);

  GridLayoutFactory.swtDefaults().numColumns(4).equalWidth(true).margins(15, 5).spacing(1, 1).applyTo(body);

  new Label(body, SWT.LEAD);
  addButton(body, "RR");
  addButton(body, "3");
  new Label(body, SWT.LEAD);

  addButton(body, "7");
  addButton(body, "5");
  addButton(body, "R6");
  addButton(body, "1");

  addButton(body, "74");
  addButton(body, "we");
  addButton(body, "FL");
  addButton(body, "23");

  addButton(body, "R4");
  addButton(body, "R3");
  addButton(body, "R2");
  addButton(body, "R1");

  // Horizontal spacer

  final var spacer1 = new Label(shell, SWT.SEPARATOR | SWT.HORIZONTAL);
  GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().applyTo(spacer1);

  // Right aligned close button

  final var closeButton = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
  closeButton.setText("Cancel");

  closeButton.addListener(SWT.Selection, event -> shell.close());

  GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().align(SWT.END, SWT.CENTER).grab(true, false).applyTo(closeButton);

  // Layout and open shell

  shell.layout();
  shell.pack();

  shell.open();

  // Block until closed

  final var display  = shell.getDisplay();

  while (!shell.isDisposed())
   {
     if (!display.readAndDispatch())
       display.sleep();
   }

  display.update();
}


private static void addButton(final Composite body, final String text)
{
  final var button = new Button(body, SWT.PUSH | SWT.FLAT);   // Flat style is optional here

  button.setText(text);

  GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().hint(75, 40).applyTo(button); // Adjust hints to change button size to suit

  button.addListener(SWT.Selection, event ->
    {
      labelTxt.setText(text);

      button.getShell().close();
    });
}
```